# Get image path from IsolatedStorage Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, onedrive

I am trying to upload Images from my phone to One drive but I am constantly getting Exception :

> Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Following is my code from button click to Uploading of file. btw I am able to upload a sample file without any trouble which i create myself but cant access images in my phone.

Here is my code.

```
 private async void btnUpload_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (await skydrive.UploadFile(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/sample_photo_00.jpg") == OperationStatus.Completed)
                    MessageBox.Show("The file has been uploaded!");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

The Definition of the `UploadFile` Function is

```
 public async Task<OperationStatus> UploadFile(string fileName)
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var fileStream = store.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read ))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (liveClient == null)
                            await GetSkyDriveFolder();

                        LiveOperationResult res = await liveClient.UploadAsync(subFolderID,
                                                    fileName,
                                                    fileStream,
                                                    OverwriteOption.Overwrite
                                                    );
                        return OperationStatus.Completed;
                    }
                    catch 
                    {
                        return OperationStatus.Failed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you access the same image "sample_photo_00.jpg" already for display purpose? If the image is already used in a reading stream, you can't access the same source with ReadWrite.

Comment: Just a guess: try to replace FileAccess.ReadWrite with FileAccess.Read. If this doesn't help, you might want to identify the exact line which throws the exception.

Comment: I tried using FileAccess Read but it gave me error thats why i changed it to ReadWrite to check if it worked but it doesnt. The exact exception code line is : if (await skydrive.UploadFile(@"isostore:/Shared/ShellContent/sample_photo_00.jpg") == OperationStatus.Completed)